# iOS turn off word byte matching

Tags: ios, ipad, notes.app, text-input

Is there a way to turn off iOS's matching of space separated collections of letters?

Let's say I have the below line in (for example) the factory supplied "Notes" app:

```
Find ways to deal with iOS's logic
```

and I later decide to insert `Need to` to the start of the `Find ways...` line by touching at the start of that line, but forget to add the trailing space, so that second line would be:

```
Need toFind ways to deal with iOS's intuitiveness
```

After moving the cursor away from the junction of `...to` & `Find ways...`, when I then try and place the cursor between the two originally separate words in the last sentence, to add the space, iOS will instead only "snap" the cursor to either side of the combined words, and offer me the option of choosing from iOS's guesses at the spelling of what it assumes is one word.

Comment: I didn't have a problem putting the cursor between `in` and `Find` when trying this, what exactly happens here in your situation?

Comment: @patrix - Please see edit to my question, to add to what options I seem to get in this situation.

Comment: Would whoever down voted this question, please explain how it does not show research effort, is unclear or not useful?

Comment: Does `toFind` get underlined in red then?

Comment: How are you trying to place the cursor in the middle of "toFind"? If you tap the word, the cursor ends up at either the beginning or the end, but if you tap-and-hold until the loupe appears, you should be able to place the cursor in between characters as expected. Does that not happen?

Comment: @patrix - No red underline.

Comment: @DanJ - That's it. Was not holding my finger on the display, was just touching it. Pity both ways are not available to do this. Want to put this into an answer so I can mark as correct?

Comment: Done. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only tap a word, the cursor will end up at either the start or the end, depending which you tapped nearer to. You must tap and hold your finger on the screen until the magnification loupe appears - you can then position the cursor between characters.